# Добавление записей в столбец с записями

Tags: sqlite3

Нужна помощь, возможно ли добавить в столбец с уже имеющейся записью еще одну запись?
На картинке видно, что в столбце txt есть уже запись, можно ли туда добавить еще запись, при этом не удаляя старую запись, если нет, то как по другому решить данную задачу?

[image: моя бд]

Comment: вы хоть опишите смысл этого действа? какую логику вы пытаетесь релиазовать?

Comment: чем вам не угодило добавление еще одной строки?

Comment: @teran. я пытаюсь сделать избранное, куда пользователь сможет добавлять записи с интересующим его контентом

Comment: может стоит почитать немного теории про связи, один ко многим там, многие ко многим. нормализацию данных и т..п?

Comment: @teran может вы и правы, если скините стоящий источник, то буду благодарен